# Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 side by side on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-mac-2022

I'm new on mac. Does anybody know if VS 2019 and VS 2022 can run side by side on a **Mac**? And If it is posible have someone had issues?

Comment: It has always been possible to install different versions of VS side by side - quite common, really.

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio for Mac 2019 and 2022 work side by side. If you use the installer for Visual Studio for Mac 2022 it will move the Visual Studio for Mac 2019 app bundle to another location (it will not overwrite it).